# make problem: No rule to make target /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so

Tags: compiling, make

I am following this tutorial to run one of the examples provided by PCL (point cloud library): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXK95Hi4M7I

But when executing the make command (https://youtu.be/CXK95Hi4M7I?t=243) I get the following output:

```
yalishanda@yalishanda-thinkpad-x200:~/PCL/visualRangeExample/build$ make
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so', needed by 'range_image_visualization'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could someone tell me what the issue is and how I can solve it?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

The Makefile generated by cmake:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.5

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named range_image_visualization

# Build rule for target.
range_image_visualization: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 range_image_visualization
.PHONY : range_image_visualization

# fast build rule for target.
range_image_visualization/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build
.PHONY : range_image_visualization/fast

range_image_visualization.o: range_image_visualization.cpp.o

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.o

# target to build an object file
range_image_visualization.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.o
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.o

range_image_visualization.i: range_image_visualization.cpp.i

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.i

# target to preprocess a source file
range_image_visualization.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.i
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.i

range_image_visualization.s: range_image_visualization.cpp.s

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
range_image_visualization.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.s
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.o"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.i"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(range_image_visualization)

find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (range_image_visualization range_image_visualization.cpp)
target_link_libraries (range_image_visualization ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Do you have `libproj-dev` installed? Install it and try again.

Comment: @Seth yes it is already installed. I updated my post with the Makefile

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error:

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so', needed by 'range_image_visualization'.  Stop.

means that make cannot find the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so` that it needs to finish the compilation.

First check if the file exists:

```
$ stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so  
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so': No such file or directory
```

Ok, so we need to install it. The easiest way to figure out what package provides `libpcl_common.so` is using a tool called `apt-file`. Install and set it up:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

When that is finished you can run:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so  
libpcl-common1.8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so.1.8
libpcl-common1.8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so.1.8.0
libpcl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so
```

And there you go!  Install `libpcl-dev` and you should be golden.

It's also worth noting that *usually*, inside your source directory, there should be a README file with a list of the dependencies you will need to install, which should help remove some of this guessing and save some time.

Comment: btw, usually I look for packages using apt-cache. In other words here I tried  "sudo apt-cache pkgnames  libpcl", which gives way more options. But I just have no idea at all which one to install. Is it better to always use your alternative ie apt-file? How do they differ?

Comment: @trilolil `apt-cache search` just searches the package name and short description. `apt-file search` is looking inside the packages to see which one includes the file you searched for.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "missing" file was /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so.  I used your technique to look for a package containing it, but no joy.  Problem was, the cuda development install placed the required stub in another location.  I found it using:

```
$ cd /
$ find . -name libcuda.so
```

I found that the stubs actually did exist in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs.  So, I figured I don't have the skill to fix the makefile, but I can help it find what I need to complete the compile.

```
$ cd /usr/local
  (and saw that the cuda directory did not exist.)
$ sudo mkdir cuda
$ cd cuda
$ sudo mkdir lib64
$ cd lib64
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs stubs
```

...and that did the trick.  Nothing elegant, it just worked.